# How to change the Element Name in XML using minidom + python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

```
<CCC>
    <BBB>This is test</BBB>
</CCC>
```

Here I need to modify the `CCC` to `XXX`. How do I do this using minidom and Python?

Expected Output:

```
<XXX>
    <BBB>This is test</BBB>
</XXX>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the node name by setting the tagName attribute
Try this,

```
tag_ccc = dom2.getElementsByTagName("CCC")[0]
tag_ccc.tagName = "XXX"
```

This should change the tag name to "XXX", below is the test code i used to confirm this using python 2.7

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
xml ="""<CCC><BBB>This is test</BBB></CCC>"""    
dom = parseString(xml)
tag_ccc = dom.getElementsByTagName("CCC")[0]
tag_ccc.tagName = "XXX"
print tag_ccc.toxml("utf-8")
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the element name by modifying the *tagName* of the node.
For instance:

```
root = dom.getElementsByTagName('CCC')[0]
root.tagName = 'XXX'
```

You get:

```
<XXX>
    <BBB>This is test</BBB>
</XXX>
```

The documentation is available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).